# A confusing print result in StringIO

Tags: python-3.x

I’m learning StringIO in Python 3.7.4 and I meet a read and write problem and feel confused, can you tell me the reason?

```
from io import StringIO
f = StringIO('Hello\nHi!\nGoobye!')
while True:
    s = f.readline()
    if s == '':
        break
    print(s.strip())

f.write('hello')
f.write(' ')
f.write('world')
print(f.getvalue())
```

I expected:

```
Hello
Hi!
Goobye!
hello worldoobye!
```

Actual results:

```
Hello
Hi!
Goobye!
Hello
Hi!
Goobye!hello world
```

Comment: When memory read, pointer moves to end of the line. So the next 3 writing location is the end of the String. Is this correct?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning the value of f to be the "Hello Hi Goodbye" String. However, you never change this or assign a new string throughout the program so at the end when you call `f.getvalue()`, you will simply get the value of the string you initialized at the beginning of the code. Seems like after the while loop you need this.

`f = StringIO('oobye')`